# Why doesn't ionized air give you a current shock?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-current, estimation, ions

According to Tesla coil, the air gets ionized and why doesn't ionized air give current shock to a person standing in the ionized air?

Answer (score 1):

So according to my own knowledge, the air only is ionized when it IS the arc. A good way for me to think is that the charge differential between the topload on the tesla coil and a ground eventually gets so high that the electric field rips a thin "wire" of air apart into plasma and therefore can conduct a pulse of current to the ground.

You don't get shocked when youre in the field of the tesla coil because the air around it is normal un-ionized air. Its when it arcs that a thin wire of air becomes temporarily ionized.

Answer (score 1):

Ionized air becomes conductive (dielectric breakdown) and certainly can deliver a shock to a person. This is what lightning is. While injuries from lightning are relatively rare, they do happen and can be fatal.